# How to filter a named range in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with a named range CODES_RANGE=Sheet1!$A:$A. Some CODES_RANGE rows has a value "x". I need to get in a range variable (in VBA) only the rows with "x" value.

I know that I can do a for each statement, but in this case the delay time will be heavy because a lot of rows.

Is there any method or instruction that I can use to avoid an iterate cycle?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use `Range.Filter`?

Comment: Using Range.Filter will be affect to the display sheet (because the arrow at the first row)? I don't want to alter the data of the sheet.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "alter the data of the sheet." What do you actually want to do with the rows that have the value "x"?

Comment: I only need to set a Range variable with  the numbers of rows that contain the value "x". But I mustn't modify any of the sheet value nor format. I think the Range.Filter will work as the filter option in the app menu (placing the down arrow in the table header), but perhaps I might be wrong.

Comment: you want the addresses of cells having value x.? and assign it to a Range variable. There is no out of box feature i can think of. You can't do away with the loop. but i am wondering what you are going to do just with cell addresses.? if you are going to copy it to another sheet or book, you can apply Range.Filter and try Selection object.